# use ResolveUrl in script address and JQDatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-applications, resolveurl

i use this code for address script in master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")%>'></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

its working. but if use this code in aspx page:

```
<jq:JQLoader ID="JQLoader1" Theme="DarkHive" runat="server"></jq:JQLoader>
<jq:JQDatePicker ID="Date1" Regional="en" runat="server" Width="100"></jq:JQDatePicker>
```

and display this Error:

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

but if delete

```
<jq:JQLoader ID="JQLoader1" Theme="DarkHive" runat="server"></jq:JQLoader>
<jq:JQDatePicker ID="Date1" Regional="en" runat="server" Width="100"></jq:JQDatePicker>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")%>'></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

page is working. please help me for use both.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code with  where you contain <% ... %>
Example:

        " rel="stylesheet" />
        ">